# How many jokers can you use in a run or set in Rummikub?

Tags: rummikub, joker

Can I use two jokers in the same run or set or are you only allowed to use one joker per set or run?

Answer (score 2):

You can use them all.

The only restriction on jokers in [the rules](https://rummikub.com/rules/) is that you have to use a joker that you have replaced.